# What happens to the received data if we dont read from TcpClient stream

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm curios about a case in tcp streaming.

Assume that we created a TcpClient and write some meaningful request string to outgoing stream. Such as an Http request.

```
try
        {
            string requestString = "GET /Api/Test HTTP/1.1 \r\n" +
                                   "Host: 192.168.2.45 \r\n" +
                                   "Connection:close \r\n\r\n";

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();

            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.45"), 80));

            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] reqBuffer = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(requestString);

            stream.Write(reqBuffer, 0, reqBuffer.Length);
```

So response is immediately recieved from destination socket by our NIC.

Here are my questions:

1. Where are the incoming bytes stored? (Does NIC have a storage, or is it stored in RAM?)
2. What does our NIC do with these bytes if we dont read them from the application.

Read:

```
if (stream.CanRead)
{
   bufferInt = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
}
```

Comment: You can check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533988/how-much-buffer-does-networkstream-and-tcpclient-have)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with many other things, the answer is in layering.

So, let's start with the hardware:

All NICs have some internal buffer. This is the first place where any response is assembled - but it's also the level where something like TCP doesn't really mean much; all the NIC cares about is its own networking protocol, for example Ethernet or PPP. At this level, IP is just a non-differentiated payload, and IP in turn has TCP as payload (though it should be noted that the layering is far from perfect :) There's a lot of coupling between TCP and IP, for example).

This incoming data must be interpreted before you can do anything; let's skip the details and just assume that the NIC buffer now contains a nice little TCP/IP packet. Now, the NIC driver comes into play - every open port on your machine has an associated piece of memory for receiving data. Basically, this is what you control when you set `ReceiveBufferSize` and `SendBufferSize`. The driver will instruct the NIC what to do with the incoming data - usually, the NIC will send the data directly to RAM using DMA. This is very fast - modern NICs don't really need to have large onboard memory chips; even for server NICs, the amount is usually around 32 MiB.

These two RAM buffers are the most important for your question - when they are full, the NIC will simply discard any further packets that arrive. In the case of TCP, which has flow control, it will tell the other side to *stop transmitting, thank you*. In effect, this emulates the usual behaviour of buffered streams - the sender will be blocked until it's possible to send another piece of data again. When this happens, the sender will retransmit the data that didn't make it the last time. In case of protocols like UDP, there is no flow control and no retransmit, so you simply lose the data irrevocably (and without even telling you there was a problem).

If you have a pending send/receive operation (e.g. `NetworkStream.Read`), you will also be using a buffer of your own - this is yet another layer, but it's really the least important. All that's happening here is that when the OS gets an information from the NIC driver, it will fill your buffer with data from the internal buffers and signal you. In a synchronous scenario (as in your case), this will simply cause your `Read` call to return. An asynchronous scenario is somewhat trickier in that .NET and the OS interact to produce a callback, but the rest is pretty much the same. This isn't fundamentally different from reading a file from a local hard drive, for example.

One important thing to note in .NET is that the buffer you use in those sends/receives is *pinned* for the duration of the operation. This means that the buffer is forbidden to move in memory, which can reduce the effectivity of the garbage collector (preventing proper heap compaction); if you have a lot of long-running operations, you really want to reuse the buffers as much as possible - if you always create a new buffer for each operation, you will likely face issues with heap fragmentation.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is stored in RAM, the amount of ram it uses is `client.ReceiveBufferSize`. There is also a small amount of buffer memory on the network card and that will depend on the card.
2. Once the RAM buffer is full the OS will stop reading from the network card, this will cause the network card's buffer to get full and stop ACKing packets that come in. This will cause the [TCP window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_tuning#Window_size) to shrink to 0 and the sender will stop sending until it receives a ACK from the network card which will only happen once it the data leaves the network card's buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but here is a code snippet to let you play with the ReceiveBufferSize and SendBufferSize attributes.

What happens down there?

The server will not read the incoming buffer until you press enter, and when you do, you can see additional buffers are sent by the client.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8989);
        server.Start();
        server.BeginAcceptSocket(AcceptSocket, server);

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 8989);

        FileStream dataToSend = File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\videoUpload.rar");

        byte[] tempSendBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
        while ((numberOfBytesRead = dataToSend.Read(tempSendBuffer, 0, tempSendBuffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            client.GetStream().Write(tempSendBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sent", numberOfBytesRead);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void AcceptSocket(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        Socket localSocket = (asyncResult.AsyncState as TcpListener).EndAcceptSocket(asyncResult);
        while (true)
        {
            if (localSocket.Available > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Local Socket has {0} bytes pending to be received. Enter to receive", localSocket.Available);
                Console.ReadLine();

                byte[] tempReadBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int numberOfReceivedBytes = localSocket.Receive(tempReadBuffer);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes RECEIVED", numberOfReceivedBytes);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```